Silk Painting/Symbol Translation
I have inherited a beautiful silk painting and would like to know anything about it! The artist if possible. Thank you.




The signature is 白雲心 /Bai Yunxin/
The Seal read 白雲 (white cloud)
白 - White
雲 - Cloud
心 - Heart
白雲心 seems to be the name or pen name of the artist, 白(Bai = white) is the family name, 雲心(Yunxin = cloud's heart) is the first name, together  白雲心 means "heart of a white cloud"

It looks like the seal contains "白雲" only.

It looks like 心, but more like 公 !?
